# Comparar un entero con null

Tags: java, operador, null

Me encontré con este problema realizando mi programa

```
int número = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ingresa un número" ));

if (número == null) { // El compilador me marca error por comparar int con null
número = 0;
}
```

Necesito validar ese Input púes mas adelante voy a comparar la variable y si tiene valor nulo me arroja el error 'Nullpointer'

He visto en algunas publicaciones que lo mejor es crear la variable número como un objeto de la clase Integer, pero si corro el programa así, cuando llegue a la comparación de nuevo bota el nullpointer

La única solución que vi fue capturar el input en un String y después hacer parseo

Quisiera saber si hay otra alternativa, púes de esta manera me toca parsear en varias partes del codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que mezclar las dos soluciones dadas.

Como dice @eftshif0, una variable *int* (o cualquier tipo de primitiva) nunca puede ser *null*, solo pueden ser *null* las referencias a objetos.

```
Integer numero;
```

Ahora bien, *Integer.parseInt* devuelve un *int*, una primitiva, así que lo que devuelva nunca será *null*. Así que si haces

```
Integer numero = Integer.parseInt(string);
```

el compilador lo que hace es equivalente a

```
Integer numero = new Integer(Integer.parseInt(string)); *1
```

y es seguro que *numero* no será un *null* (porque siempre le asignas un objeto).

La cosa sería que solo le asignes el integer si es una opción numérica. Además, deberías asegurarte de que el valor que te pasan se pueda convertir a entero y no te dé excepciones.

```
String cadena = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "ingresa un número");
Integer numero = null;
if ((cadena != null) && !cadena.isBlank()) {
   try {
      numero = Integer.parseInt(cadena);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO tu proceso del error porque te han metido algo que no es un número.
   }
}
```

*1 de hecho si miras la documentación verás que es *Integer.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(string))* Pero para lo que nos afecta es equivalente.

Answer (score 1):

El dato ingresado en el JOption es un String por lo cual puede validar

```
dato == null;
"".equals(dato.trim());
```

Si las validaciones son falsas entonces convierte a número

```
int numero = Integer.parseInt(dato);
```